# Where should I install the drain saddle for a reverse osmosis system in this plumbing?

Tags: plumbing

I am trying to install a reverse osmosis (RO) system under the kitchen sink. I need a drill a hole for the drain. I cannot decide where to drill as it might be very noisy due to constant noisy leakage if it is in a wrong place.

[image: under sink view showing existing plumbing]

Comment: it is dripping not running, so you wont hear it

Comment: please elaborate

Comment: connect before P-trap, between sink drain and p-trap

Comment: "The drain saddle assembly should be installed above the trap and on the vertical or horizontal tailpiece . To reduce the drainage noise, mount the drain line as low as possible above the trap, or on the horizontal tailpiece. Drill 1/2” diameter hole for standard RO faucet." - So, as high as you can get it on that 2" vertical stub for the disposal (any lower and it's *in* the trap).

Answer (score 1):

In your case the best spot would be in the straight pipe where the dishwasher comes in just below it.

You can hand unscrew that pipe and disconnect the dishwasher hose and take it out for easier working on it to dill the hole and mount the drain clamp.

[image]

Comment: OP might even be able to put a Tee or Wye on the dishwasher connector and attach the RO drain line to the other opening on that (an adapter or two might be necessary to get to the right size), and not need to drill at all.

Comment: @FreeMan Even better, move the dishwasher drain over to the disposal and then hook the RO drain to the tailpiece / adapter or two.

Comment: Good point, @RobertChapin - disposals usually have a dishwasher drain connector built right in. This way, solids from the dishwasher can get chewed up by the disposal instead of going directly down the drain.

Answer (score 1):

This post has been up for a while, but I just installed a ro unit in a very tight sink space.  There was no room for the drain saddle and no easy way to reconfigure.  I found on Amazon a product made just for the ro drain.  It Y s into the dishwasher drain line right where it connects to the garbage grinder.  There was no need for the saddle or drilling.  It claims no drip noise, and I don't hear any so it is perfect for my problem.  I thought I'd post in case there are others still having similar issues.  Here is the description:

Universal Garbage Disposal Drain Line Adapter (DLA) For a Water Filter 3/8-inch Quick Connect Fitting up to 7/8-inch fitting for a Dishwasher (DA-DWRO-06, ET116-02,DLA-D-38JG,DLA-D-38QC,WP164020)

Note that it says 3/8", but you can order it for 1/4, 3/8, or 1/2"